# this graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware [NVIDIA]

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, nvidia-graphics-card

I wanted to downgrade my Nvidia driver version from 340.43 to 337.50. I used software called " Display Driver Uninstaller " to remove my current driver version. after restart , I tried to install 337.50 versions. then I got this error " this graphics driver could not find compatible graphics hardware"

what is that? how to fix it? 
Help me please
now , device manager not detect my nvidia GPU.
and my gpu is new.

spec : 
GPU : Nvidia GeForce GT720M
CPU : Intel Core i3 - 3217u 1.8GHZ
RAM : 4GB

Comment: You can't.  Your trying to use a driver that isn't support by your GPU.  Even if you manage to hack the driver its unlikely going to work.  What problem are you trying to solve by downgrading the driver?  Try using a stable release driver.

Comment: **`GeForce 332.21 Driver - WHQL` is the earliest version you can use but don't use the current stable release.**  Stop using "driver" programs they are snake oil, all you need to do to uninstall NVidia drivers, is to uninstall them using the Control Panel.  I verified the version I suggest works for 8.1x64

Comment: i tried 337.50 before and worked. this problem came since i uninstall my driver using DDU ( Display Driver Uninstaller )

Comment: Yes; Try my suggestion; the program you used likely is the sole reason you have this problem so stop using snake oil programs

Comment: Still not working..

Comment: if i reinstall my windows , will this problem come again?

Comment: I cannot predict the future but I can tell you reinstalling Windows isn't a solution either

Comment: do you have another solution?

Comment: Okay, do you see Nvidia Geforce Gt720M(Microsoft wddm) listed under display adapters in device manager? If not, try searching for a device with hardware id as 10de under other devices. Then try Inf installation. This will only fail if driver.package does not have the device id listed